# Put ToolBar above ActionBar android

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar, toolbar

I have an `ActionBar` and a `ToolBar` in my Activity. The `Actionbar` is on the top of the screen and ToolBar is right below the `ActiconBar`. I'd like to change this situation to the opposite. I'd like to `ToolBar` to be the top of the screen and the `ActionBar` below. Is there any way to do this?

**Check the layout file below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="hu.redbuttonebb.endi.fragmentek20.SearchActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:id="@+id/searchvagyok">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    layout="@layout/toolbar2"
    android:title="xxxxxxx">
</include>
```

**toolbar2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:background="#808080"
app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search">
```

**ManiFest.xml**

```
 <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    </activity>
```

**Activity.java**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search2);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFD700")));
    ab.setTitle("5gdgdgddf");

    mToolbar2 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    }
```

Comment: ToolBar is the replacement of Action Bar, I wonder how you could place it above one other.

Comment: the Toolbar has it's purpose and the purpose is to replace actionBar if you need some non-standard behaviour, so the only method you should call is setSupportActionBar(toolbar); If you want to have some custom view - put it to Toolbar

Comment: I'd like to have one Actionbar to write the title of the Activity, and one below for searching.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing there, since the app should have either ActionBar or Toolbar. If you need another container for your controls or something, just use horizontal linear layout. Anyway, I think that you could have two, by using two Toolbars, and setting one as the action bar, by ` setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should get rid of the ActionBar, as @LvN said, the toolbar is the replacement of the ActionBar.

Second, you could have two toolbar, one above another, and in the Activity set the bottom one for being the "action bar" with **setsupportactionbar()**

Comment: @J.Doe You should check this answer